# How to perform join query in update?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to join two tables.

One table has a column `status(varchar)`

Second table  column  `actis(Boolean)`

We have perform query like to join two tables if status is active it is True otherwise it is False .

```
update seclogic_users 
set is_active=False 
from employee 
  inner join seclogic_users 
    on(seclogic_users.id=employee.id)
where employee.status='archived' or 'incomplete'
```

Please share where to modify.

Answer (score 2):

Don't repeat the table being updated in the `from` clause.  You also have to fix the `in` clause:

```
update seclogic_users su
    set is_active = False 
    from employee e
    where su.id = e.id and
          ew.status in ('archived', 'incomplete')
```

Answer (score 0):

only thing I could see wrong with your query was the where clause

```
update seclogic_users 
set is_active=FALSE
from employee 
  inner join seclogic_users 
    on(seclogic_users.id=employee.id)
where employee.status in ('archived', 'incomplete')
```